# Add event listener to Pika IOLoop or multithread?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, rabbitmq, pika

I'm writing a utility which is supposed to act as a consumer for a `RabbitMQ` Queue. It retrieves messages, does certain things with them, and submits them to another system like f.e. `Riemann` or `Statsd`.

Right now the communication with `RabbitMQ` uses the async `SelectConnection` adapter, the communication with the output (`Riemann`/`Statsd`) uses the `python-riemann`/`pystatsd` client (which are blocking).

I believe I could improve the overall performance of this utility by modifying the `python-riemann` and `pystatsd` client to also use an async adapter (I'd have to write that one), but my problem is that I'm not sure how to combine that with pika's `IOLoop`.

According to my understanding I think I would probably have to find a way to add event listeners on the pika `IOLoop` which should trigger when `Riemann` or `Statsd` responds, because according to my current understanding there is no good way how I could have two event loops, unless I multithread the utility and have one `IOLoop` for the connection to `RabbitMQ` in thread `#1` and another one responsible for the output (`Riemann`/`Statsd`) in thread `#2`.

So my question is: What's the best thing to do, multi thread this utility and have one `IOLoop` per external system I'm interacting with, or trying to find a way to also use pika's `IOLoop` for a purpose that it has probably not been intended for.

Comment: `pika` has support for twisted's event loop, and there's library called [`EagleEye`](https://github.com/hawkowl/eagleeye) that runs on twisted and can talk to riemann. If that has all the features you need, it's probably the easiest way to get them integrated.

Comment: If you want you can also use a simpler, thread-safe library like https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy or https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm